# SQL select for many to many relationship using binding table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

I am struggling with writing a select for diagram on the picture.[image: picture]

What I want to do is write a select, which will show me details of a car repair. As you can see in table `Repairs` there are only 2 attributes but I am not sure if it's necessary to add more, especialy those from `employees_list` and `parts_list`, since I want to show repair data for every vehicle by it's `plate_number`. By repair data I mean repair `id`, vehicle `plate_number`, all employees working on the repair and all parts used on the repair. If my diagram is wrong, please help me fix it and I have no idea how to write select for this because of the many to many relation and the use of binding tables.

Comment: Yes, it would be hard to do a big select and join every data together, but if you want something more specific, you should specify in your question what do you exactly want to select from the db.

Comment: What I want to select is all repair data as I mentioned. Repair data means repair id, vehicle plate, all parts used, all employees who worked on the repair. Also, I am not quite sure if binding tables are necessary in this case because even though its many to many relation, its always not in real time many to many, so wouldn't it be easier/possible without binding tables?

Answer (score 0):

This is not so hard as it may seem.

First, obviously, we have to select cars:

```sql
select vehicles.* from vehicles
```

then, let's join repairs:

```sql
select 
    vehicles.* 
from vehicles
    inner join repairs on vehicles.id = repairs.vehicle.id
```

We don't need data from repairs in resule set, so we just join it but not mention in 'select' part.

Then we have to join parts needed for repair, and info about parts itself:

```sql
select 
    vehicles.* 
from vehicles
    inner join repairs on vehicles.id = repairs.vehicle.id
    inner join parts_list on parts_list.repair_id = repairs.id
    inner join parts on parts_list.part_id = parts.id
```

For that query we get amout of rows equivalent of amount of parts needed for repair. But it would be more easy to handle such data in code if we aggregate all of them into json column. So in result set we willsee something like:
vehicle_id, vehicle_part, parts_needed_as_json

Lets aggregate this:

```
select 
    vehicles.*, json_agg(parts.*) as parts_needed 
from vehicles
    inner join repairs on vehicles.id = repairs.vehicle_id
    inner join parts_list on parts_list.repair_id = repairs.id
    inner join parts on parts_list.part_id = parts.id
group by vehicles.id, repairs.id
```

Now you can add same logic for employees:

```
select 
    vehicles.*, 
    json_agg(parts.*) as parts_needed,
    json_agg(employes.*) as employees_needed
from vehicles
    inner join repairs on vehicles.id = repairs.vehicle.id
    inner join parts_list on parts_list.repair_id = repairs.id
    inner join parts on parts_list.part_id = parts.id
    inner join employees_list on employes_list.repair_id = repairs.id
    inner join employees on employees_list.employee_id = employees.id
group by vehicles.id, repairs.id
```

BTW, I suggest you to rename your tables to lowercase and singulars. 
Like: 'repair', 'employee' and 'vehicle';

Also, name your binding tables like: 'repair_part' and 'repair_employee'. 
Some people even suggest to arrange related tables in that names by alphabet, like: 'employee_repair' and 'part_repair', but I think it's not required;

Maybe this is a question of taste but in most cases this leads to more readable queries.

I.e, the query above will looks like:

```sql
select 
    vehicle.*, 
    json_agg(part.*) as parts_needed,
    json_agg(employee.*) as employees_needed
from vehicle
    inner join repair on vehicle.id = repair.vehicle_id
    inner join parts_repair on parts_repair.repair_id = repair.id
    inner join part on parts_repair.part_id = part.id
    inner join employees_repair on employees_repair.repair_id = repair.id
    inner join employee on employees_repair.employee_id = employee.id
group by vehicle.id, repair.id
```

Note how elegant 'on' conditions looks now: parts_repair.part_id = part.id, parts_repair.part_id = part.id

Sorry for bad english

Comment: Also, you probably have to add 'repair_date' to repairs table.

Comment: I tried to edit your code but I have no privillege to edit yet. You have one code part not formatted. Hmm, so the query at the end should work right?

Comment: Yes, it should work if you have correct table schema with adjusted table names.

Comment: Before I can try this select, I am trying to implement a form to add employees and parts into the repair. How can I add multiple employees and parts into that repair?

Comment: You have to use 'empoyes' and 'parts' tables as 'directory' or 'dictionary'.
First, you fill them with actual list of parts / employes not related to repairs. 
Second, you assign parts / employes to specific repair by filling employes_repairs / parts_repairs tables.

Comment: So when I want to create a new repair for one vehicle, for example in my form I have dropdown select list where I load all employees from table `employees` and I insert all selected employees into table `employees_repair` with `repair_id` ? There is no need for `<PK>` in table `employees_repair`? Is it going to insert somethin like `repair_id = 1` `employee_id = 3`, `repair_id = 1` `employee_id = 5`, `repair_id = 1` `employee_id = 7`, ...?

Comment: You almost correct except some small nuances. 

PK is required in every table. There are very very rare cases when you don't need PK. This is not the case )
For tables employe_repairs and part_repairs PK is composite of two fields (employee_id, repair_id) and (part_id, repair_id).
In all other details you are completely correct.

Comment: Okay. So basically when I am creating completly new repair for vehicle, I have to follow these steps: 1. Choose what employees are working on this repair. 2. Insert those employees with repair id into `employees_repair` table. Same for the parts. 1-1. select parts for this repair. 2-2. insert those parts into `repair_parts` table. And then I have my repair ready for the select you wrote in your answer above, correct?  Im trying to implement this in my view and model, please stay in touch :) thanks

Comment: Okay so I have done inserting into `employees_repair` table. For now, I am going to skip `parts` and try it with employees only to see if it works. I have tried your code but I get syntax error. Aren't you missing some commas or brackets?

Comment: The error I get is `Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "vehicle" ... `

Comment: It saying that you don't have table named 'vehicle'. So, if you are using second version of my query you have to rename tables. Read query, try to understand it's logic, don't just copy paste.